# How to turn off Flutter page transition animations

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have a Flutter MaterialApp.

When I navigate between pages it makes a slide left animation.
I don't want any transition animations between page changes.

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    //home: MainScreen(),
    initialRoute: '/',
    routes: {
      '/': (context) => MenuPage(),
      '/page2': (context) => Page2(),
    }
  ));
}
```

#### How do I turn off the page transition animations ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the below code to navigate without animation.

```
    Navigator.push(context, PageRouteBuilder(pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => 
       YourScreenName(), 
       transitionDuration: Duration(seconds: 0),
     ),
   );
```